# Solutions to make my image clickable without hover jitter

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've run out of ideas. I have a website I'm making. My first one. With only CSS3 HTML JS. I'm going to switch to bootstrap when I finish this current version just want to iron out the bugs.

Here's a js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/JKenny209/f98r32ba/#&togetherjs=I31aD4vBcy

My current problem is that I have an image that enlargens on hover and when you click this hover it takes you to a modal with more details about a topic but when I removed the jittery bug that comes from hover, I lost the ability to click any part of the image to open the model. I can now only click where the red and blue box does not overlap ( It's only visible for the image that is row 2 column 2). The blue box is the `:hover: after` pseudoelement.

I've tried selecting the :hover:after pseudoelement in js to make that the on click event. However, I can't seem to select both :hover and :after with 
`window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".column2-row2"), 'hover::after')`in js.

Any solution js or non js related is welcomed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this maybe work

```
.column2-row2:hover::after{
    z-index: -999;
}
```